# Excel sheet automate sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel spreadsheet and I want to add data to A2-A30 each time. Is there a way to make a  new sheet with the name of the data without typing it in everytime?

Macros in vb scipt.I have tried a macro vb script but did not work.

Answer (score 0):

The follow code must be helpful - it does work for me:

```
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    Sheets(2).Name = "SheetName"
```

Be aware, that (2) is Sheet index - it may be different every time you run the macro, so adapt the code as you need.